# Put div class on top of navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this fork me ribbons make in CSS. The idea is that they have to be on top of the navbar, just as the actual github images.
This is how it looks right now: http://jsbin.com/womib/1

```
 .ribbon {
      background-color: #F38419;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: absolute;
      left: -50px;
      top: 40px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
           -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
              transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .ribbon a {
      border: 1px solid #faa;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      font: bold 81.25% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 1px 0;
      padding: 10px 50px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;
    }
```

I want to position then on top of the navbar, but I'm getting this result.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to the `.ribbon` class: `z-index: 9999;`.

You need to set the z-index higher than the navbar to get it to work like how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a `z-index` value bigger than your navbar for your `.ribbon` class, just like @Aibrean said.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's navbar has the Bootstrap sticky-top class by defualt. Which, has a z-index of 1020. To put your ribbon in front of the navbar, you need to make your ribbon's z-index larger than 1020. Add the following style to your ribbon class to put your ribbon in front of Bootstrap's navbar:

```
z-index: 1021;
```